# Retry mechanism with observable

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm trying to write retry mechanism using C# observables.

1. Retry has a retry count and retry interval
2. Retry should execute "OnExecute" method.
3. On every exception it would execute "OnCatch" method.

Here is what I tried to do:

```
public static IObservable<T> Retry(GenericRetryExecutorRequest<T> request)
{
    var source = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, request.Interval)
        .Select(item =>
        {
          return request.GenericRetryActions.OnExecute();
        });

    var retryObservable = source
        .Retry(request.RetryCount)
        .Catch(source);

    return retryObservable;
}

public class GenericRetryExecutorRequest<T>
{
    public int RetryCount { get; set; } = 3; 
    public TimeSpan Interval { get; set; } = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,5);
    public IGenericRetryActions<T> GenericRetryActions { get; set; }
}

public interface IGenericRetryActions<out T>
{
    T OnExecute();
    void OnCatch();
}
```

Unfortunately - it doesn't perform well:

1. I do not know how to execute `OnCatch` when exception is thrown.
   I've tried many ways with no success.
2. `OnExecute` doesn't seems to perform repeatedly (with the request
   interval) in case it throws an exception.

Comment: What should happen on a successful execution? Should it terminate? Or keep firing?

Comment: @sholomo it should be terminate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static IObservable<T> Retry<T>(this GenericRetryExecutorRequest<T> request)
{
    return Observable.Timer(Timespan.Zero, request.Interval)
        .Select(item =>
        {
            try
            {
                var value = request.GenericRetryActions.OnExecute();
                return Notification.CreateOnNext(value);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                request.GenericRetryActions.OnCatch();
                return Notification.CreateOnError<T>(e);
            }
        })
        .Dematerialize()
        .Retry(request.RetryCount);
}
```

Generally using try-catch inside an observable is frowned upon; it is preferred to use the observable On-Error exception handling. However, your interface's `OnExecute` doesn't return `IObservable<T>`, rather just `T`. So you're forced to use try-catch. If you were to change the interface to return `IObservable<T>`, then I think this would work:

```
public class GenericRetryExecutorRequest2<T>
{
    public int RetryCount { get; set; } = 3;
    public TimeSpan Interval { get; set; } = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5);
    public IGenericRetryActions2<T> GenericRetryActions { get; set; }
}

public interface IGenericRetryActions2<out T>
{
    IObservable<T> OnExecute();
    void OnCatch();
}

public static IObservable<T> Retry2<T>(this GenericRetryExecutorRequest2<T> request)
{
    return Observable.Timer(Timespan.Zero, request.Interval)
        .SelectMany(_ => request.GenericRetryActions.OnExecute())
        .Catch((Exception e) => Observable.Return(Unit.Default)
            .Do(_ => request.GenericRetryActions.OnCatch())
            .SelectMany(Observable.Throw<T>(e))
        )
        .Retry(request.RetryCount);
}
```

That's all assuming you want the mechanism to keep firing on success. If not, add a `Take(1)` at the end of either solution.

Comment: thanks a lot ! can you tell me please why do u use SelectMany instead of Select ?

Comment: SelectMany is used in cases where you would end up with a nested observable, but you prefer flat. It flattens a nested observable. It is equivalent, for most cases, to .Select(selector that produces observable).Merge().

Comment: Can you please supply a unit test for the second code ? here is my shot:
var mockObject = new Mock<IGenericRetryActions<bool>>();
            var request = new GenericRetryExecutorRequest<bool>
            {
                GenericRetryActions = mockObject.Object
            };

            GenericRetryExecutor<bool>.Retry(request).Subscribe(done =>
            {
                mockObject.Verify(mock1 => mock1.OnCatch(), Times.Never());
                mockObject.Verify(mock2 => mock2.OnExecute(), Times.Once());
            }); 

But unfortunately - I can't make it to the Verify.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about `Observable.Interval(x)` being equal to `Observable.Timer(Timespan.Zero, x)`. It is equal to `Observable.Timer(x, x)`. Answer edited. Unit test code passes now.

Comment: toda my friend :)